# Passing a question mark in URL does not work on live server but on local server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-encoding

I have a SEO-friendly URL which contains a URL-encoded news title. We use mod_rewrite to split the URL and pass different parameters to PHP:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index\.php\?content=news&newsId=$1&title=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

This way, we can access the title string with PHP using e.g. `$_REQUEST['title']`.

If the title string contains a question mark, our development system (WAMP) will still have the whole title string within `$_REQUEST['title']`. But our production system (LAMP) will cut off the string before the first occurence of a question mark.

Who knows which configuration is responsible for this behaviour? Is this an Apache setting or a PHP setting?

### Example

**Test title:**

*Why do we do this? In order to test*

**Test URL:**

`/news/123/Why+do+we+do+this%3F+In+order+to+test`

**Test script:**

```
echo var_export($_REQUEST['title'],true);
```

**Output on local server:**

```
'Why do we do this? In order to test'
```

**Output on live server:**

```
'Why do we do this'
```

Comment: Try the [`B` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) or using `%{THE_REQUEST}` instead of `%{QUERY_STRING}`. I'm guessing the Apache versions aren't the same on both servers?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @ishegg. I never used the B flag before, but it doesn't solve the problem. If I add it, the live server's output becomes `Why+do+we+do+this`

Comment: I see. How about the `QSA` flag?

Comment: @ishegg no, does not work either. Also, `QSA` would intentionally behave differently when having two question marks, which I do not want. I want Apache to not "see" the question mark within the string.

Comment: Live system: Apache/2.4.27 (Unix)
Local system: Apache/2.4.16 (Win64)

Comment: As long as you are sending encoded value `%3F` instead of `?` it should work.

Comment: @anubhava that's what we expected, but it's not the case.

Comment: WHerever it is not working, enable `RewriteLog`, collect the logs and post it here in question.